# Specifiying url pattern inside of AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer's getServletFilters

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

Inside of my web app initializer that extends `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` I am setting up my servlet filters by overriding the `getServletFilters` method. I would like to specify the url patterns for these filters but I can't find a way to do it.

```
    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] {
            new CharacterEncodingFilter() // specify url pattern?
        };
    }
```

Comment: Override and implement `registerServletFilter` to register the filters as you see fit.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  Even then I am not seeing how I would specify the url pattern. `protected Dynamic registerServletFilter(ServletContext servletContext, CharacterEncodingFilter filter) {
  return servletContext.addFilter("CharacterEncodingFilter", filter);
 }` and would I have to "override" this method for every filter I want to register?

Comment: `addFilter` returns a `Dynamic` where you can specific which url patterns to support. No, you override the method once for all filters. If you need to do a different mapping for each of the filters, consider scrapping `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` and use your own `WebApplicationInitializer`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Oh ok, I understand now. For now the solution I found is to Override `onStartup` and set each filter individually there.